# Laravel / Eloquent: nested WhereHas

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've just started learning Laravel and stumbled upon one issue which I can't make work using the Eloquent relationships.

Let's assume that I have a Worker model, a Skill model and a pivot table skills_workers to keep the many-to-many relationship.
When I'm trying to get all the workers, who have following skill, then it goes without a problem using the following syntax:

```
    $skill='carpenter';

    $workers=Worker::whereHas('skills', function (Builder $query) use($skill){
            $query->where('name','=',$skill);
    })->get()();
```

The problem begins when I need to find all workers who have the set of skills. For example, carpenter-driver-chef (just for example). If the worker should have one of the skills, then I'd just use the whereIn function, but I need to find the worker who posess all of the skills in array.
I can't make the nested WhereHas as every time the user performs a search the skill set might be different. Sometimes it's just 1 skill, sometimes 2 and so on.
So the following construction:

```
    $skills=['carpenter','driver'];

    $workers=Worker::whereHas('skills', function (Builder $query) use($skills){
            $query->where('name','=',$skills[0]);
    })->whereHas('skills', function (Builder $query) use($skills){
        $query->where('name','=',$skills[1]);
    })->get();
```

is not an option.

Is there a way to use whereHas inside of a foreach loop, for example? Or, maybe, there is a more elegant way of performing such queries? None of the other posts on StackOverflow that I've found, helped...
I'd really like to avoid using the raw SQL queries, if possible.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

As your `$skills` variable appears to be an array, you could use the Eloquent `whereIn` function.

```php
$workers = Worker::whereHas('skills', function (Builder $query) use ($skills) {
    $query->whereIn('name', $skills);
})->get();
```

**Update**

The following should get you a collection of `Workers` that have all the `Skills`.

```php
$workers = Worker::whereHas('skills');

foreach ($skills as $skill) {
    $workers->whereHas('skills', function (Builder $query) use ($skill) {
        $query->where('name', $skill);
    })->get();
}

$workers->get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, whereIn works as an "Or", so in my case it would find all workers who have "carpenter" skills and all workers who have "driver" skill, but not the ones, who posess both skills at the same time

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is working! I need some time to digest how exactly it works, nevertheless it does work nicely!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use foreach for skills to get multiple matching condition

```
   $workers=Worker::whereHas('skills', function (Builder $query) use($skills){
               foreach($skills as $value){
            $query->where('name',$value);
         }
                
    
        })->get();
```

Comment: Nope, as the skills_worker pivot table has only one skill in one record, so such a construction won't produce anything.

Comment: if i understand your question correctly.you need list of  workers whos skill matches all the skills passed from $skills right

Comment: Yes, indeed. And if there would've been a direct link between workers and skills table, your solution would've worked. However, in this case it goes this way:
1) It finds the record in pivot table with the first skill
2) After that, it checks if the same record contains the second skill as well.
But the record always contains just one skill, so there won't be any results, unfortunately...

Comment: can you post some data and what exactly you expecting result .so we can check how it look like

Comment: Thank you John, but @Peppermintology has already given the solution that works. Hope it helps other people with the same problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with getting all `skills` and after that you can use `whereIn` like this

```
$skills=['carpenter','driver'];

$skills_id = Skill::whereIn(['name',$skills])->pluck('id');
```

By using `pluck` the query will return an array of IDs `[1,3,...]` not model.

```
$workers = Worker::whereHas('skills', function(Builder $query) use ($skills_id) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $skills_id);
})->get();
```

Comment: Same as above -  whereIn works as an "Or", so in my case it would find all "carpenters" and all "drivers", but no all "carpenters, who are drivers"...

Comment: Do you want to retrieve only worker who are `carpenter` and `driver` at the same time or all cases

Comment: only workers who are 'carpenter' and 'driver' at the same time, not all the cases