# Laravel whereHas relation where column can be equal to any in array but no other

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build an Eloquent query to find a model that has relations where their column is equal to one of the given values, but no other. For example, a model could have several relations those column contains one of the given values, but have another relation that doesn't and should therefore be omitted.

All I have so far is a whereHas query that finds the models whose relations contain the values. This works exactly as it should, but I want to omit the models that contain a relation without these values, even if they have a relation that does.

```
$query->whereHas('conditions', function($query) use ($category_ids) {
  $query->where('conditionable_type', EmployeeCategoryOption::class)
        ->whereIn('conditionable_id', $category_ids);
});
```

I've searched the docs but can't find any Eloquant method that does what I'm after.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT (example scenario)

Conditions table:

```
id | conditionable_id | option_id
1  | 1                | 1
2  | 2                | 1
3  | 3                | 1
4  | 3                | 2
5  | 4                | 3
```

I would like to get all of the options that have a condition with a conditionable_id equal to 3 or 4 and no others. In the above table this would return option's 2 and 3 as option 1 also has conditionable_id's 1 and 2.

Comment: is it $query->whereHas('conditions', function($query) use ($category_ids) {
  $query->where('conditionable_type', '!=',EmployeeCategoryOption::class)
        ->whereNotIn('conditionable_id', $category_ids);
}); this you looking for ?

Comment: Hello @JohnLobo. Thanks for your comment. This will find relations that do not have the values or class i'm looking for. Im looking for relations with that class and only those values.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67858394/281278

Comment: @Peppermintology, thanks for your comment. This answer will get all relations that have all of the values.

Comment: Maybe add some example data to clarify what it is you're asking.

Comment: Hello @Peppermintology, I've added to my question, hopefully it helps better explain what I'm after!

Comment: @Peppermintology, please let me know if theres anything else I can do to better explain as this question has been flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the opposite of the `$category_id` as `$notCategoryIds`

```
$query->whereDoesntHave('conditions', function($query) use ($notCategoryIds) {
    $query->where('conditionable_type', EmployeeCategoryOption::class)
        ->whereIn('conditionable_id', $notCategoryIds);
})->whereHas('conditions', function($query) {
    $query->where('conditionable_type', EmployeeCategoryOption::class);
})
```

If you dont have the invert category list, do it like this.

```
$query->whereDoesntHave('conditions', function($query) use ($category_id) {
    $query->where('conditionable_type', EmployeeCategoryOption::class)
        ->whereIn(
            'conditionable_id', 
            \DB::table('conditionable_option')->where('conditionable_type', EmployeeCategoryOption::class)
                ->whereNotIn('conditionable_id', $category_id)
                ->pluck('conditionable_id')->toArray();
        );
})->whereHas('conditions', function($query) {
    $query->where('conditionable_type', EmployeeCategoryOption::class);
})
```

You can change that pluck query inside to a query builder form instead of a fetch result query to make it faster using some joins and aliases.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @N69S. This filters the relations returned rather than the parent models.

Comment: @JackTempleman it does both. If it is not what you needed, please add an exemple in your question to better explain what you need to recover.

Comment: I've added to my question. Your answer returns option 1 but only condition 3.

Comment: Thank you @N69S for your time. The above works perfectly. I was hoping there would be an elegant solution within Eloquent, but this works brill. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addSelect()` to only add the models you need based on your query.

```
$query->whereHas('conditions', function($query) use ($category_ids) {
  $query->where('conditionable_type', EmployeeCategoryOption::class)
        ->whereIn('conditionable_id', $category_ids);
})->addSelect(['conditions' => Condition::select('field')
    ->whereColumn('your_field_id', 'condition.id')
    ->where('conditionable_type', EmployeeCategoryOption::class)
    ->whereIn('conditionable_id', $category_ids);
]);
```

You could refactor the `addSelect()` to a custom scope function on your model.